# Symfony2: Doctrine read some fields as null whereas they are not

Tags: symfony, collections, null, doctrine, nested

the problem I am facing is relatively complex..

Some fields that have been filled in the form are however considered by Null by Doctrine ORM upon Flush.

I guess I have to start with the specific background.

I am working on an "article" entity that works on a three-tier nested collection.
The Article object has a collection of "components" ( more or less Columns) which in turn are divided in "Sections" (Consisting of a text with a title) that can end up in a collection of links at the bottom.

I am mentioning this as it could be a possible cause of dysfunction, as my JavaScript code for collections has a lot of room for improvement. Be that as it is I must specify that the code for the nested Section collections is already fully operational. The form is correctly displayed and it saves.

I have been working on adding the links nested Collection in the past two days and I have managed to make it display normally (including overloading prototype with indexes ) However when I try to submit my form. I have trouble with two fields marked as required/ not null. The form cannot be persisted because those values are null. However those input fields are not.

Link objects have "name" "url" "image" "group" and "section"
The last two attributes are filled outside of form. Image is nullable.
name and url are the two faulty attributes. They are marked as null when they shouldn't be.

If you are familiar with collection prototyping in symfony, you know that some text in the prototype as to be replaced to display proper index in html label and attributes.
For instance in my case:
 `name="article[components][0][sections][0][links][0][URL]"` 
This works and for this I replace all occurrences of the following texts:  `__name__`, `__sectionName__` and `__linkName__` in my prototype.
I had a mistake in my link prototype:  `__slinkName__` in the html name attribute of the Link object name value. Curiously it made doctrine accept that field's value. I tried mistyping both it didn't work. I tried mistyping the line that generates the url field instead and it again made doctrine accept the other field's value (the name field)but not the one I had mistyped.

As such my conclusion was that there was an issue with my JavaScript. However
I made a var_dump about jsust before flush and the fields are correct.

Here's an excerpt from Controller that matches what I just described:

```
 foreach ($article->getComponents() as $col){
                foreach($col->getSections() as $section){
                    if ($section instanceof Section && $section->getImage()){
                        $section->getImage()->setFolder('country/'.$country.'/'.$topic);
                    }
                    foreach($section->getLinks() as $link){


                        $link->setGroup($group);
                        var_dump($link);
                        if($link instanceof SectionLink && $link->getImage()){
                            $link->getImage()->setFolder('country/'.$country);
                        }

                    }
                    die();
                }
            }
            $em->flush();
```

Now the var_dump:

```
protected 'id' => null
protected 'image' => null
protected 'name' => string 'Google' (length=6)
protected 'url' => string 'www.google.fr' (length=13)
```

What could possibly cause doctrine to consider those two fields null?
At this point something prevents Doctrine from knowing the value that should be inserted into link.name is called 'name'.

I should add that the SectionLink entity is inherited from a Link entity and adds the Section attribute for the ManyToOne relationships.
I have had problems in the past regarding inheritance and Doctrine so it's also a possible lead...

Thanks in advance to those who can help.. I have no clue what's going on...

Comment: A little update. I set both field to accept null values and I tried filling the two separately and it worked. After that  I was able to fill link objects with both values at same time.. All was fine except.... now remove/delete doesn't work. Removing the collection element in JavaScript doesn't delete it from DB anyway. And yes the collection formtype has option allow_delete set to true. I think there's something messed with Doctrine but I don't know what..

Comment: I thought I had figured it out...  Only managed to fix the delete problem...(Had an attribute called group, which is a reserved word in MySQL )

Comment: Now when I add a second  element to a link collection it starts treating all the fields as null. It feels as if the form elements are not synchronized with corresponding object........